# Why does my msgbox always returning to true?

Tags: javascript

Why does my msgbox always returning to true??

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function deletesubj(x){
    var conf = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this subject?"){
         return true;
    }
    else{
     return false;
}
}</script>
```

Comment: Maybe try writing valid javascript first

Answer (score 1):

Check the condition after:

```
var conf = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this subject?")
if (conf) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ive done what you said but its always returning to true even i click the cancel.